# Joomla - Using different templates for the Home page and for the other pages

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-template

How can I use different template for the Home page, and different template in the inner pages ?

Comment: You mean randomly? please detail your question (also please tell which Joomla version)

Comment: @ jackJoe - Not Randomly. I need to use 2 different templates for my Joomla project. Eg: one template for the home page and another one for the inner pages. I use Joomla 2.5.
In this web site they have used 2 templates : http://openskies.lk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Joomla! you can assign templates to menu choices.

**Joomla! 1.5**

In Joomla! 1.5.x you do it in the template. i.e. Select `Extensions->Templates` then click on the template you want to assign to a menu position. Once in the `Template  [Edit]` screen you can use the "Menu Assignment" panel on the bottom left to specify which menus use the template.

**Joomla! 2.5**

In Joomla! 2.5 you can set where the template is used in both the Template (similar to J1.5) and you can select it directly in the menu when you're creating it.

Don't forget that in Joomla! 2.5 a template can have "style" variations that you can create and use just like a the base the template.

Answer (score 0):

In joomla you can assign different templates for inner pages. Use

```
Extensions->Template Manager
```

You can see all the template files. Select a template file to edit the details. You can see an option like "Menu Assignment", Select those menus which needs to use the selected template. Also make sure in the template index file, you have loaded the component. Otherwise the components will not be loaded.

```
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```